# How to use direction route object to get data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

With the code below, I display a journey betwen two points.

Now I try to use direction result object and direction leg to get information like steps, legs or distance in a variable, but I have no idea to how use this method...

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(44.912198, -0.605530);
var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(44.893356, -0.739138);

function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: haight
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    calcRoute()
}

calcRoute()

function calcRoute() {

    var request = {
        origin: haight,
        destination: oceanBeach,
        // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
        // using square brackets and a string value as its
        // "property."
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to `console.log(response)` within the if `if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {` statement. Watch your javascript console and that should help you get started. We don't really know what information you need and what you want to do with it.

Comment: [Example that gets that information from the directions response and displays it on a google map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved a part of the problem with this code :

Variable duration, path, and polyline1 are ok, I've tried it with an alert.

Now I want to save those variables in a data base like sql, how I do ? using php ?

```
function calcRoute() {
 var request = {
     origin: start,
  destination: end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
};
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  var warnings = document.getElementById('warnings_panel');
  warnings.innerHTML = '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  showSteps(response);
}
 });
}

function showSteps(directionResult) {

 var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {


var duration = myRoute.steps[i].duration.text;

var path = myRoute.steps[i].path;

var polyline1 = myRoute.steps[i].distance.text;


}
}
```